# Image Links in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Can anyone tell me how do I convert this into CakePHP code :

```
<a href="portfolio/01.jpg" rel="lightbox[portfolio]"><img src="portfolio/01.jpg" alt="Image 01" /></a>
```

at least without this part:

```
rel="lightbox[portfolio]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('/portfolio/01.jpg',array('alt'=>'Image 01')),'/portfolio/01.jpg',array('rel'=>'lightbox[portfolio]', 'escape'=>false));
```

Comment: Oh, its working, now the images have links, thanks dude. But it doesn't show me the image when I click on it. My be some jQuery sliding issue, what do you think ?@luboss